# How can I share videos to my AppleTV using the Raspi?

Tags: media-server

Currently I am using my AppleTV together with my iTunes library on my Mac. That's fine, but it would be even better if I could use my Raspi to serve the media. I could just mount a share from the Raspi on the Mac and import the files into iTunes. But I'd like to be able to use the AppleTv and the Raspi alone. I found the [daapd](http://elinux.org/RPiForked-Daapd) solution in the Wiki, but that seems to only serve music. Is it possible to extend this to video as well?

Comment: I have shairport (https://github.com/albertz/shairport) now up and running, which works fine for the Raspberry to be an audio sink. Still looking for the video serving solution still.